# How should I pass multiple DateTime parameters to an ApiController method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

(I'm using WebApi 4.0.20710.0, with framework 4.0. I'm not sure if this is important, but we haven't been allowed to upgrade our servers to 4.5 yet)

What I want to do is make a call like this :

```
http://domain/api/Books/Outstanding/2013-01-01/2014-01-01
```

In my `ApiController` I have a method something like this :

```
/// <summary>
/// Get a list of books that were outstanding between the start and end dates.
/// </summary>
public IEnumerable<BookDto> GetOutstanding(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return _repository.GetOutstanding(start, end);
}
```

And in my `RouteConfig` I have a route defined like this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ActionWithStartAndEnd",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{start}/{end}"
);
```

Yet none of this actually works. I end up with an error message that says simply `"No action was found on the controller 'Books' that matches the request."`

I suspect I'm doing something simple incorrectly, and/or have misunderstood something about routing in general. How should I be doing this?

Comment: But your action name is `GetOutstanding` not `OutStanding`

Comment: I had to anonymise the code, possibly badly. Frankly the defaults are misleading. I'll remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

The route doesn't belong in RouteConfig, it belongs in WebApiConfig, and it should take this form :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionWithStartAndEnd",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{start}/{end}"
);
```

Comment: +1 for coming back and making a clear answer! Don't forget you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer in a couple of days when I'm allowed (unless someone else manages to chip in with more eloquent deprecation ;)